# How to add variables inside the for loop of Jinja python

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to loop over a product list{more so a queryset} in django using for loop, by adding the range of products 
The following code works when printed out in cmd prompt

```
for card in allproduct[nextRangePage:limit]:
    print(card.name)
```

But the Jinja pattern fails for some reason

```
{% for card in product[{%'nextRangePage'%}:{%'limit'%}] %}
```

The error is

**django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[{%'nextRangePage'' from 'allproduct[{%'nextRangePage''**

The context variables are:

```
context = {
'product': product_list,
'pages': pages,
'nextRangePage': nextRangePage,
}
```

**[product_list = allproduct]**

Comment: try: `{% for card in allproduct | slice:limit %}` or `{% for card in allproduct | slice(limit) %}`

Comment: It didn't worked, gave an error **'for x in y': %s" % token.contents)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for card in allproduct | slice:limit**

Answer (score 1):

You never nest Jinja `{{...}}` or `{%...%}` markers.  Instead of:

```
{% for card in product[{%'nextRangePage'%}:{%'limit'%}] %}
```

You need:

```
{% for card in product[nextRangePage:limit] %}
```

For example, given the following code:

```
import jinja2

product = [{'name': f'item{i}'} for i in range(10)]

t = jinja2.Template('''
{% for card in product[nextRangePage:limit] %}
{{ card }}
{% endfor %}
''')

print(t.render(product=product, nextRangePage=2, limit=8))
```

The output is:

```
{'name': 'item2'}

{'name': 'item3'}

{'name': 'item4'}

{'name': 'item5'}

{'name': 'item6'}

{'name': 'item7'}
```